# Add Mesh to an imported wireframe object

Tags: objects, import, faces, wireframe, remesh

I am beginner. I have imported an object which has no faces (only edges and vertex). Import from dwg. What is the best way to add a clean mesh to the object? The object is a chair.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there's any automatic way to do it, you can try to fill the faces with some F (then knife tool to cut edges, or J), or Ctrl F > Grid Fill, or right click > LoopTools > Bridge, etc...

Comment: please share the file so that we can give a try

Answer (score 0):

What I did, I had the imported wireframe object in object mode and have add a plane where I snapped the 4 vertices to the edge/vertices of the wireframe. From there I extruded 2 selected vertices along the the wireframe. This works somehow, put the topology is not great and I was hoping that there is a smarter way to do it.

[image]

[image]